# How can I filter documentdb records based on timestamp?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using documentdb database since long,

thus it has lots of records/documents in collections,

No to simplify it I want to fetch records/documents based on timestamp.

1. I want to fetch all records which are created in last 1 day.
2. I want to fetch all records which are created in last 15 days.
3. I want to fetch all records which are created in last 1 month.
4. I want to fetch all records which are created in last 1 year.

I have tried to rite query like this but its not working.

```
var curDate = new Date().getTime();
SELECT * FROM r WHERE r._ts >= @curDate AND r.studentId=@studentId
```

Comment: `I have tried to rite query like this but its not working` .... Can you tell what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date().getTime()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) say

> A number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

`_ts` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-working-with-dates) say

> a number representing the number of elapsed seconds since January 1, 1970

So you are comparing milliseconds to seconds, which won't yield any results.

You need to divide the first value by 1000 before you compare it to the second value. And, of course, you need to subtract 1 day, 1 month or whatever value you need, e.g.

```
var twoDaysAgo = new Date();
twoDaysAgo.setDate(d.getDate() - 2);
var threshold = twoDaysAgo.getTime() / 1000;

SELECT * FROM r WHERE r._ts >= @threshold AND r.studentId=@studentId
```